# Adding a linear search

Tags: python, tkinter

Trying to add a search feature to search for key words within this code:

```
button1 = tk.Button(f1, text='Year 12, Paper One', command=lambda:raise_frame(f2)).pack()
button2 = tk.Button(f1, text='Year 12, Paper Two', command=lambda:raise_frame(f3)).pack()
button3 = tk.Button(f1, text='Year 13, Paper One', command=lambda:raise_frame(f4)).pack()
button4 = tk.Button(f1, text='Year 13, Paper Two', command=lambda:raise_frame(f5)).pack()

tk.Label(f2, text="Year 12, Paper One").pack()
tk.Button(f2, text="HOME", command=lambda:raise_frame(f1)).pack()

tk.Label(f3, text="Year 12, Paper Two").pack()
tk.Button(f3, text="HOME", command=lambda:raise_frame(f1)).pack()
tk.Label(f4, text="Year 13, Paper One").pack()
tk.Button(f4, text="HOME", command=lambda:raise_frame(f1)).pack()
tk.Label(f5, text="Year 13, Paper Two").pack()
tk.Button(f5, text="HOME", command=lambda:raise_frame(f1)).pack()
raise_frame(f1)
root.mainloop()
```

and this is the current search I have created - is this correct and where should I place this in code?

```
def sequentialSearch(alist, item): 
     pos = 0 
     found = False 

     while pos < len(alist) and not found: 
         if alist[pos:pos+len(list(item))] == list(item):
             found = True 
         else: 
             pos = pos+1 

     return found
```

Comment: not sure what's going on with that search. Do you want to just see if `item` is in `alist`? why not just do `if item in alist: return item` or something?

Comment: So im adding information within each button, and i want the search to search for a word the user enters from the text in the button

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to put the code somewhere in the `command` of the button.

Also, if I understand you correctly, you can shorten the `sequentialSearch` function quite a bit

```
def sequentialSearch(alist, item):
    return item in alist
```

Python's [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) operator checks to see if `item` is a member of `alist`, and I assume it just does a sequential search for it.

Examples:

```
alist = ['a','b','c']
item = 'b'
print(item in alist) # True
item = 'd'
print(item in alist) # False
```

Comment: So i'd place it just above the top lines in my question?

Comment: no? you would need to explain a lot more what you are trying to do. What should happen depending on if the item is found or not? Does it apply to all the buttons? Is that search supposed to run on each button click? (in which case, you need to call that function on a button click, which I assume is the `command` I referred to)